# How to switch x/y in trendline expression?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, trendline

Without switching axis on chart itself, what is the easy way to switch x and y for the given expression like `y = 3E-12x5 - 4E-09x4 + 1E-06x3 + 0.0005x2 - 0.0302x + 23.826`. So I would like to get `x` for the given `y` series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create a chart to derive a polynominal regression, you can used `LINEST` and then for your problem, simply swap the x and y ranges

See [here](http://people.stfx.ca/bliengme/ExcelTips/Polynomial.htm)

[image]

Comment: But LINEST will not display equation, right? What I needed is equation for swapped x/y. I've tried and it gave me me just single value.

Comment: It  will - it will give you all the coefficients if you follow the advice above (remember to array enter the formula)

Answer (score 0):

You have a function y(x) which is a high order polynomial. And you want to find the function x(y)? Try the inverse function calculator at [wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/gallery/view.jsp?id=d08726019e4a2a15cb1d49092e4d0522).

Answer (score -1):

To do so, in your desired graph, draw the corresponding trend-line and select the trend-line equation to be shown; Then using the option "Switch Row/Column" in design tab, switch the graph. You will see that the both the graph and also the equation change. 
Simply by clicking on the equation so that the text cursor appears in the text field where the equation is written, then the equation will become fixed. Then again, click on "Switch Row/Column" in design tab. You will see that the graph turns to the initial condition, but the equation does not. 
Now you have your desired graph and the equation of the function inverse showing on the graph.

Good Luck,